# Build a Line UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

Is it possible to build a WPF **UserControl** `SegmentControl`, having similar to the Line shape coordinates (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2)?

I already built a custom Line *`Shape`*, but I need an *`UserControl`*, because I add some additional customizable elements, like text and bullets to it.

I built some code, but think I need help:

```
<UserControl>
<!-- internal Canvas; The UsrCtrl Parent is supposed to be a Canvas too -->
    <Canvas>
        <Line x:Name="line" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"></Line>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Paris - Moscow"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

*.cs

```
public partial class SegmentControl : UserControl
{
    #region dependency properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X1Property;

...
static void OnXYChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SegmentControl s = source as SegmentControl;
    UpdateControlPositionAndSize(s);
}

static void UpdateControlPositionAndSize(SegmentControl sc)
{
    double left = Math.Min(sc.X1, sc.X2);
    double top = Math.Min(sc.Y1, sc.Y2);

    double width = sc.X2 - sc.X1;
    double height = sc.Y2 - sc.Y1;

    Canvas.SetLeft(sc, left);
    Canvas.SetTop(sc, top);
    sc.Width = width;
    sc.Height = height;

    sc.line.X1 = sc.X1; // ??
    sc.line.Y1 = sc.Y1; // ??
    sc.line.X2 = sc.X2; // ??       
    sc.line.Y2 = sc.Y2; // ??
}
```

Comment: What does X1 Y1 and X2 Y2 means in this context? Are they coordinates of your segment inside your control?

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet x1, y1, x2 and y2 means the same thing like for a Line shape it mean. the coordinates of the line (in my concrete case in a Canvas) "extreme" points.

Answer (score 3):

What about just creating a custom `DependencyProperty` on the UserControl of the Points you need, and binding your Line position to it?

Your UserControl would be something like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Canvas>
        <Line x:Name="line" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
              X1="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:SegmentControl}}, Path=StartPosition.X}"
              Y1="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:SegmentControl}}, Path=StartPosition.Y}"
              X2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:SegmentControl}}, Path=EndPosition.X}"
              Y2="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:SegmentControl}}, Path=EndPosition.Y}" />

        <Label x:Name="label" 
               Content="{Binding={RelativeSource RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type my:SegmentControl}}, Path=Text}"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

You would use it something like this:

```
<my:SegmentControl 
    StartPosition="{Binding Path=StartPoint}"
    EndPosition="{Binding Path=EndPoint}" 
    Text="{Binding Path=SegmentText}" />
```

Comment: this code is cool, however, with StartPosition (0,0) the line should be in the upper left corner of the container..., however this is not the case, because "line" position is relative to UC, but the StartPosition - tot the UC parent., Also, there should be a way to bind the UC Canvas.Left etc properties... )

Comment: Instead of binding the line's X1:Y1 to StartPosition, bind the UserControl's `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` to StartPosition, and set the X1:Y1 to 0:0. Leave the Line's X2:Y2 bound to the EndPosition