# How to build a Line User Control on WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

What is the best approach to build a Line User Control like the one in Expression Blend?
I posted a similar question weeks ago, and also read this artcle: [Build a Line UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317389/build-a-line-usercontrol)

but still haven't found a solution.

The real problem is that using a drawing routine like:

```
public LineControl()
{
    startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(null);
    _frgPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3);    
}

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    Point p1 = this.PointFromScreen(startPoint);
    Point p2 = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

    drawingContext.DrawLine(_frgPen, p1, p2);
}
```

the starting point is not the point clicked on the WPF Designer and, a later resize of the control will cause the line to be radrawn from a starting point that doesn't match with the "real" starting point.

Can someone please help me in this?